# JQuery Mobile Slider Handle (JSFiddle Provided)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Here is a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vxee5b79/7/

HTML:

```
<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" min="1" max="9951" value="1" step="50">

<div data-role="rangeslider" data-track-theme="b" data-theme="a">
  <input type="range" name="range1" id="range1" disabled="disabled" min="0" max="10">
  <input type="range" name="range2" id="range2" disabled="disabled" value="10">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-btn.ui-slider-handle {
    display: none;
}
```

My question is when I add the above CSS it takes away the slider handles on both sliders as expected. Is there a way I can keep the handle on the top slider while removing the handle on the bottom slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to place any sliders that need the handle hidden within a container DIV:

```
<div class="hiddenHandle">
    <input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" min="1" max="9951" value="1" step="50">    
</div>
<div data-role="rangeslider" data-track-theme="b" data-theme="a">        
    <input type="range" name="range1" id="range1" disabled="disabled" min="0" max="10" value="2">        
    <input type="range" name="range2" id="range2" disabled="disabled" min="0" max="10" value="6">   
</div>
```

Then the CSS can use that class:

```
.hiddenHandle .ui-btn.ui-slider-handle {
    display: none;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/vxee5b79/8/)**

If you don't want the container, you can use CSS like this:

```
#slider-1 + .ui-slider-track .ui-btn.ui-slider-handle {
    display: none;
}
```

jQM creates a slider track DIV next to the INPUT, so the CSS gets that DIV and finds the handles within it using the **[Adjacent Sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)**

> **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/vxee5b79/9/)**

Comment: Thanks for the help and the link to the adjacent sibling selector!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a more specific selector, like this:

```
.ui-slider-handle.ui-btn.ui-shadow.ui-btn-a {
display: none;
```

}